# How to - if condition is met, then write selection to file

Tags: php, forms, file, conditional-statements

I have the following PHP code that checks which choice from a radio button was selected and then write to a file of the same name.

For example, from a Radio button group called "instrument", where the 4 choices are

1. Wind
2. Strings
3. Percussion
4. Vocal

**If the user selects "Wind"**, then it would create and write to a file called "**wind_instrument.txt**". If "strings" is selected it would create the file "string_instrument.txt" and so on.

Here is my PHP code:

```
if ($_POST['instrument'] == "wind")
{


$lines = file('wind_instrument.txt');
$fopen = fopen("wind_instrument.txt", "w+");

}

elseif ($_POST['instrument'] == "strings")
{

$lines = file('strings_instrument.txt');
$fopen = fopen("strings_instrument.txt", "w+");

}

elseif ($_POST['instrument'] == "percussion")
{

$lines = file('percussion_instrument.txt');
$fopen = fopen("percussion_instrument.txt", "w+");

}

elseif ($_POST['instrument'] == "vocal")
{

$lines = file('vocal_instrument.txt');
$fopen = fopen("vocal_instrument.txt", "w+");

}
```

**Now, if one of the conditions is met, would then go on to the next step in my code, being:**

```
fwrite($fopen, ("Instrument: ")."");
fwrite($fopen, $_POST["instrument"]."\n");
fwrite($fopen, ("<br>")."\n");
```

**The problem** I have with this, is that it is not creating a file, and I do have permissions set.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You should use the [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) construct to make your code more readable

Comment: Have you verified that this is really a problem with writing to a file based on a conditional? If you create a test script that just opens and writes "test" to a single file, does that work or does it give you the same problem?

Comment: your script worked as is on my system, so it is probably a permission problem on your public dir served by your webserver, or a problem with your calling html form.

Comment: @ilanco thanks but I don't know how to use that.

Comment: @dAm2K I have made a test script and it does work, but only if there is one choice and writes to a particular file.

Comment: @Fred this is because of the elseif. Just remove them and replace with if

Comment: @dAm2K Yessss! Beautiful, it worked. Many thanks to you, and everyone for the suggestions, cheers! Enjoy your day :)

Comment: @Fred pay attention to 2 problems: 1) opening the file "w+" will place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length, overwriting your user's choices; 2) your code is not safe because (rare but not impossible) two or more users could (open and) write the same file concurrently, possibly breaking the file content.

Comment: @dAm2K The file needs to be APPENDed as new content is to be added. For 2) I would need to Lock the file, yes?

Comment: @Fred YES. You need to flock() the file, but you still could not be sure 100% that the resource get locked exclusively, for example on systems where multiple threads serve clients or on system where flock() is not implemented in a secure way

Comment: @dAm2K what would you suggest?

Comment: @Fred use a DBMS like MySQL or Sqlite instead of a file.

Comment: @dAm2K It's a great suggestion, but if I knew how to work with those, would have been the way to go, for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually could do some refactoring in order to make it easier to maintain, nevertheless that wasn't your problem but I shall try to help you out.

```
<?php
  $instruments = array('wind', 'strings', 'percussion', 'vocal');

  if (in_array($_POST['instrument'], $instruments))
  {
    $instrument = $_POST['instrument'];
    $file_handle = fopen($instrument.'_instrument.txt', 'a+');
    $line = 'Instrument: '.$instrument."\n";
    fwrite($file_handle, $line);
  }
?>
```

The **important** thing to know is how I open the file. I use the mode **a+**. The documentation says

> Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, very much appreciated. I will give that a try and write a new code file and see how it works out. Enjoy your day :)

Comment: I replaced your code in the section where mine was, and am getting an Internal Server Error. Where exactly am I to put it?

Comment: That's not their problem -- opening with `w+` also opens the file and if necessary attempts to create it. However, you're probably right that they want `a` and not `w`. a appends new lines to the file if it already exists, whereas w overwrites any information that was already there.

Comment: @Fred there was a syntax error, not corrected. Please retry now.

Comment: @Fred Sorry... I made the edit, but still: This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed

Comment: @dAm2K Oh boy... "peer reviewed", I'm new here, so I don't know what that's about (lol)

Comment: I've approved the edit. I defined the array as a literal. Always forget that PHP suck and don't have that. Thanks @dAm2K for spotting it!

Comment: @Kevin Sjöberg Thank you very much, I appreciate it a lot. It worked beautifully :) and thank you Kevin as well, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you've verified that you have permissions to open and write to a file, then there should be no problem with doing it based on a conditional. I suggest checking the contents of `$_POST` and making sure that `instrument` is present and meets one of your conditions. Alternately, you could add an `else` clause that will write the submission to an error file if no valid instrument was received. If that works, it would confirm that the problem is with the POSTed variable, not with fopen/fwrite.

If the options you provided in the bulleted list are the literal values of your radio buttons, then your problem is that they're capitalized and the values you test in the `if` statement aren't. Either capitalize them consistently, or use `strtolower()` to convert everything to a consistent case before comparing.